# Get element of an array on click

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a small project where I show informations about every country in the world via an API

[image]

Where I'm struggling here is that whenever I click on a card I want to show a modal with more informations about the country

This part works nicely, BUT whatever the card I click on it's always going to be the last element of the array informations that I'm going to get

For exemple, If I click on "Afghanistan":

[image]

I get the last element of the array (the array being every card), which is Zimbabwe

This is my code

Basically the "country" parameter is the API data

What I'm doing is looping through every card and adding an event listener on click and trying to get all the informations about the card in the modal... but it doesn't work, I only get the last card infos

```
function showModal(country) {
  const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

  for (card of cards) {
    card.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      openModal.classList.toggle("active");

      openModal.innerHTML = `
      <div id="modal">
      <div id="close-modal">
        <i class="gg-close"></i></i>
      </div>
        <div id="modal-img">
          <img src="${country.flag}">
        </div>
        <div id="modal-content">
          <div class="country-details">
            <h2>${country.name}</h2>
            <h4>Nom natif : <span>${country.nativeName}</span></h4>
            <h4>Population : <span>${country.population.toLocaleString()}</span></h4>
            <h4>Région : <span>${country.region}</span></h4>
            <h4>Sous-région : <span>${country.subregion}</span></h4>
            <h4>Capitale : <span>${country.capital}</span></h4>
          </div>

          <div class="country-details">
            <h4>Domaine de premier niveau : <span>${
              country.topLevelDomain
            }</span></h4>
            <h4>Monnaie : <span>${country.currencies}</span></h4>
            <h4>Langues : <span>${country.languages}</span></h4>
            <h4>Fuseau horaire : <span>${country.timezones}</span></h4>
            <h4>Indicatif téléphonique : <span>${
              country.callingCodes
            }</span></h4>
            <h4>ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 : <span>${country.alpha3Code}</span></h4>
          </div>

          <div class="country-details">
            <h4>Pays frontaliers</h4>
            <span>${country.borders}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      `;

      /* Close Modal */
      const closeModalBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("gg-close");
      closeModalBtn[0].addEventListener("click", (e) =>
        e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove(
          "active"
        )
      );
    });
  }
}
```

I don't know much about arrays yet

Thanks!

Comment: Is your function `showModal` supposed to show the modal for the country it receives?

Comment: Ever heard of [`<template>`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)?

Comment: The structure of your code is a little confusing. Maybe I'm not reading right, but it looks like you have a function `showModal` that you call for a specific country, but inside of that function you are assigning an event listener for every card, and each card represents a country. So you're going through all of the countries for every country.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that each time you call `showModal`, you are adding an event listener to *all* cards. Instead, you should add an event listener to the card corresponding to the country it received. That's why you should add some kind of id to each card, so you can tell which country goes in which card.

Assuming each card has an id equal to its country's name:

```
function showModal(country) {
  const card = document.querySelectorAll(`#${country.name}`);

  card.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    openModal.classList.toggle("active");

    openModal.innerHTML = `
    <div id="modal">
    <div id="close-modal">
      <i class="gg-close"></i></i>
    </div>
      <div id="modal-img">
        <img src="${country.flag}">
      </div>
      <div id="modal-content">
        <div class="country-details">
          <h2>${country.name}</h2>
          <h4>Nom natif : <span>${country.nativeName}</span></h4>
          <h4>Population : <span>${country.population.toLocaleString()}</span></h4>
          <h4>Région : <span>${country.region}</span></h4>
          <h4>Sous-région : <span>${country.subregion}</span></h4>
          <h4>Capitale : <span>${country.capital}</span></h4>
        </div>

        <div class="country-details">
          <h4>Domaine de premier niveau : <span>${
            country.topLevelDomain
          }</span></h4>
          <h4>Monnaie : <span>${country.currencies}</span></h4>
          <h4>Langues : <span>${country.languages}</span></h4>
          <h4>Fuseau horaire : <span>${country.timezones}</span></h4>
          <h4>Indicatif téléphonique : <span>${
            country.callingCodes
          }</span></h4>
          <h4>ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 : <span>${country.alpha3Code}</span></h4>
        </div>

        <div class="country-details">
          <h4>Pays frontaliers</h4>
          <span>${country.borders}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    `;

    /* Close Modal */
    const closeModalBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("gg-close");
    closeModalBtn[0].addEventListener("click", (e) =>
      e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove(
        "active"
      )
    );
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By not having `const` or `let` in the *for*-loop `card` will be set globally and always hold the last the last value, since the "click" event is triggered asynchronously (after the loop is done iterating). Adding `const` or `let` to:

> ```
> for (card of cards) {
> ```

Will scope `card` to the *for*-loop and let the callbacks refer to their respective value of `card`, instead of all callbacks referring to the last value of `card`.